# como valido mis checkbox

Tags: javascript

```js
var BTN = document.getElementById("boton");


var gFinal = 0;

BTN.addEventListener('click',sumaGasto,true)

function sumaGasto(){
    

    var validaciones =document.getElementsByClassName('check').checked;
if(validaciones){
  
  var gFinal = ( sumaChecks);
  document.querySelector("#gastoFinal").innerHTML = "$"+gFinal;
}
else{
  alert ("Seleccione Una opcion");
}
   
}
```

```html
  <h2>Gasto final</h2>
        <h2 id="gastoFinal">0.00$</h2>
        <button type="button" id="boton" class="btn btn-primary">Calcular</button>
        <br><br>
```

Estoy trabajando con varios checkbox, pero... quisiera validar que al menos uno de ellos sea seleccionado por el usuario (No predeterminadamente).
pero solo logro el siguiente resultado:
("La fraccion de mi codigo")

Lo que hace es que detecta que todos los check estén seleccionado para proseguir y quiero que con uno seleccionado al azar pueda continuar.

Comment: ¿Y dónde están tus checkboxes?

Comment: Lee la sección [¿Cómo creo un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que sigas los consejos y aumentes tus posibilidades de recibir una respuesta a tu problema. Para mas información puedes visitar la página de [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help).